# ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below.

```
Table Name:activity.
coloumn name:
activity_id,Date,assign_engr,Task_Type, Task_Status
1,2013-12-31,Sachin,Monthly,Scheduled
2.2013-12-23,Mikel,Weekly,Done
```

I need a report like below format

```
Date    Monthly Task    Weekly Task Assign Engr Task_Status
```

and i have below query:

```
select b.Date,(select a.Task_Name from activity a where a.Task_Type='Monthly' and a.Date=b.Date) AS Monthly,(select a.Task_Name from activity a where Task_Type='Weekly' and a.Date=b.Date) AS Weekly,b.Task_status from activity b;
```

it is showing below error.

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

please help me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Date, 
       CASE 
        WHEN Task_Type='Monthly' THEN Task_Name
       END AS Monthly,
       CASE 
        WHEN Task_Type='Weekly' THEN Task_Name
       END AS Weekly,
       Task_status 
FROM activity;
```

In your current query you have used subqueries, like this `select a.Task_Name from activity a where a.Task_Type='Monthly' and a.Date=b.Date`. From the error it looks like that the subquery is returning more than one record because your table may have more than one record where task_type is 'Monthly'. This creates a problem because the database can use only one value in the outer SELECT statement so now it cannot figure out which value should be used out of the many values returned by the sub query. Hence an error is displayed.

The approach I have used is to remove the subqueries and use [CASE expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) instead.

Comment: Did you noticed that there is no column called Task_name in his question. I think we both missed it :)

Comment: @AshReva good catch but I think the column is there. OP may have missed to mention that in the question. I have this opinion because of the current error message. Otherwise the error message could have been something like invalid column.

Comment: I agree with you as he would have first got unknown column error rather than subquery error

Answer (score 1):

```
 select a.Date,Case when a.Task_Type='Monthly' Then a.Task_Name Else '' End as Monthly,
 case when a.Task_Type ='Weekly'Then a.Task_Name Else '' End as Weekly,
 a.Task_Status from activity a
```

In your query you dont need to do self join to activity table.

Here is Updated [enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0b33/2)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. it is almost work as per my demand. But one thing is that i am getting Null value if no weekly/Monthly activity on a day. I want as like that it should be blank. 
| Date       | Monthly                                  | Weekly                       | Task_status |

| 2013-10-14 | NULL                                     | Weekly RCA Tracker           | Scheduled   |

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am getting null value in some field. is it possible to keep blank at that field instead of NULL.

Comment: @user3114551 yes possible. see updated fiddle and query in my answer. Can you accept answer if you are satisfied.